# MariaDB Closes Frequently

Tags: mariadb, vps

I've VPS on Digitalocean Centos 7.

But it gives an error when I try to share my wordpress posts.

Here's my logs.

```
170302 09:00:03 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
170302 09:00:03 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
170302 9:00:03 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52-MariaDB) starting as process 31156 ...
170302 9:00:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170302 9:00:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170302 9:00:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
170302 9:00:03 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170302 9:00:03 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137756672 bytes) failed; errno 12
170302 9:00:03 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170302 9:00:03 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
170302 9:00:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170302 9:00:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170302 9:00:03 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
170302 9:00:03 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)
170302 9:00:03 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 72499200 bytes)
170302 9:00:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170302 9:00:03 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170302 9:00:03 [ERROR] Aborting
170302 9:00:03 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

170302 09:00:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

Comment: The error message seems to be self-explanatory. It wants 128M for the buffer pool, can't get it, so it aborts. How much memory do you have?

Comment: I've 2gb ram on my vps server.e (sorry for late answer)

Comment: Set up a monitor (`top`-based, or whatever) to see where the memory goes. Either something else uses it, or maybe your MariaDB server is misconfigured by mistake, e.g. some buffer is set to gigabytes instead of megabytes, etc. If it turns out that `mysqld` uses so much memory on startup that it cannot allocate 128M, paste your cnf file(s).